# How to detect UWP app running?

Tags: autohotkey

```
WinWait ahk_exe onenoteim.exe
```

This was my best guess, but doesn't seem to work. I want a solution that won't trigger on another window that also contains OneNote in it's name, but can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if that's the right executable file name and your TitleMatchMode is right. If it still doesn't, there must be another problem in other parts of your script.

Here's how I detect not only UWP windows but all somewhat harder-to-detect windows:

```
; This is my fave TitleMatchMode since it's the most selective
; and gives you the highest level of flexibility.
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx

...

If WinActive("ahk_class ^#32770$ ahk_exe i)\\JPEGView\.exe$")

...

; Here, I chose not to use "ahk_class ^QWidget$" as it occurs a bit too often.
hwnd := WinExist( "GoldenDict$ ahk_exe i)\\GoldenDict\.exe$")

...

Global GC_WINTITLE := " - Google Chrome$ ahk_class ^Chrome_WidgetWin_1$"
WinWait % "New Tab" GC_WINTITLE
```